# Print out of Xpath nodes

Tags: java, xpath

In the following code I am trying to get a read out of Parent Categories, the Category that belongs to them and if they contain a sub category or not.

```
 public static void getcategories() throws Exception
{       
    XPathContext xpath = new XPathContext(new FileReader("//categorylistEN.xml"));

    NodeList categories = xpath.getXPathNodes("//CategoriesList/Category");
    NodeList scategories = xpath.getXPathNodes("//CategoriesList/Category/SubCategories/SubCategory");
    NodeList pcategories = xpath.getXPathNodes("//CategoriesList/Category/ParentCategory");

    for(int i =  0; i < pcategories.getLength(); i++)try
    {
        HashMap<String, String> pcats = new HashMap();

        Node n = pcategories.item(i);
        String pid = "  ("+n.getAttributes().getNamedItem("ID").getNodeValue()+")";
        String pname = n.getFirstChild().getNextSibling().getTextContent().replaceAll("\n", "").trim() +"  ";
        pcats.put(pname,pid);
        System.out.println(pcats);

        Node cats = categories.item(i);
        String catid = cats.getAttributes().getNamedItem("ID").getNodeValue();
        NodeList catn = cats.getChildNodes();
        Node name = catn.item(5);
        String catname = name.getAttributes().getNamedItem("Value").getNodeValue();
        System.out.println(pcats +" - "+ catname + "  =  (" +catid+")");

        Node scat = scategories.item(i);
        String sid = scat.getAttributes().getNamedItem("ID").getNodeValue();
        System.out.println(pcats +" - "+ catname + "  =  (" +catid+")" + "  =  (" +sid+")");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("NoID" );
    }
}
```

It should read out in the following format:

```
    ParentCategory =(ID) 
    ParentCategory =(ID)    Category =(ID)
    ParentCategory =(ID) 
    ParentCategory =(ID)    Category =(ID)
    ParentCategory =(ID)    Category =(ID)    SubCategory =(ID)
    ParentCategory =(ID) 
    ParentCategory =(ID)    Category =(ID)
    ParentCategory =(ID) 
    ParentCategory =(ID)    Category =(ID)
```

The parent category and category work fine but not all contain a subcategory. How do I check for the subcategory and have it print out next to the category in which it is contained?? I tried some loops successfully getting the subcategory ID's in the file but it then prints them out on every category listed, even if they do not contain the sub category.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers

Comment: Never-mind, solved this.

Comment: It might sound silly, but i this case you can post your answer to your own question, and accept it so that this issue can be closed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I did not realize I had to accept an answer to close the issue..
This was a case of just not reading the xml properly. Each parent category had an ID referenced by its child categories. So I just did a check for categories containing an ID value of pid(parentID) and printed these out along with their parents..